# soapui generic way to return ok response or fault in mock

Tags: web-services, soap, mocking, soapui

I am writing a mockservice that consists of many different webservices and operations and i need a generic way to decide if i return ok or fault. All of the incoming request share the same header so i could read it in mockservice OnRequest script and set it into some variable that i could read later.
So in all my request a have:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns:someValue xsi:type="xsd:string">12345</ns:someValue >
.... skipped
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

So in OnRequest i could do something like:

```
def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )
def arg = holder["//ns:someValue"]
if(arg == "12345"){
// set some variable to True
}else{
// set that variable to False
}
```

And then in that actual mock operation i could use script dispatch strategy to read the value and decide what to return. Anyway. The problem is that i see no way to declare variables in mock. Not the mock level nor the operation level. I could put the script to each operation, but since there is going to be a lot of operations i wouldn't want to copy-paste it so much in case i need to change it.
It is my first mock so sorry if i am missing the obvious. Could anybody point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Better way is to use MockService OnRequest event handler:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapMessageBuilder

// Decision:
if( someCondition ){

    result = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
    String fault = SoapMessageBuilder.buildFault( "Server", "Message", mockRequest.getSoapVersion() );
    result.setResponseContent( fault )
    result.setMockOperation( result.getMockOperation() );
    mockRequest.getHttpResponse().getWriter().write( fault );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually was missing the obvious here. There actually is a Custom Properties tab in mock service:

[image]

and you can invoke it by using:

```
com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.setPropertyValue( "isOk", arg )
log.info(com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("isOk"))
```

---

You can also use OnRequest eventhandler:

```
result = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
String fault = SoapMessageBuilder.buildFault( "Server", "ErrorMsg" ,mockRequest.getSoapVersion() );
result.setResponseContent( fault );
mockRequest.getHttpResponse().getWriter().write( fault );
```